# Ubuntu -- Application global environment variables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, cron, upstart

So I have an application I am deploying to an Ubuntu 12 server. My application has several "parts" to it:

There's a web server, run as part of an upstart script
There are cron jobs
There are sometimes command-line utilities which I want to run when ssh-ing into the production machine

What I want is a *single place* to specify a list of environment variables (`MY_APP_HOME`, `MY_APP_CONFIG_1`, etc...), which will be picked up by *all* of those above-mentioned "parts": by the upstart script, by the cron jobs, by the login shell when I ssh into the machine.

So, questions:

1) Where's the right place to place these? Specifically -- is it `/etc/environment`? Isn't that only for login sessions?

2) If it *is* `/etc/environment` -- I notice I can't use substitutions there, or run logic. Is there any place I can do that? A set of shell commands that get source'd?

Comment: Normally you would update your upstart script, cron jobs, and utilities to read from a config file of your own doing; rather than modify the global config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple programs  /etc/myapp   e.g. /etc/wgetrc
Complex programs use a directory  /etc/myapp or /etc/myapp.d e.g. /etc/apache2 or /etc/logrotate.d
A .d in directory names typically indicates a directory containing many configuration files or scripts for a particular situation

I think its cleaner to use your own files and to set them for a user in /home/user/.bashrc than to change system wide options. If you must set it systemwide then in /etc/profile.d/myapp.sh

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.baseadmn/doc/baseadmndita/etc_env_file.htm